# Derivative of Bessel J series... Do I reindex my summation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series

Okay, short question: what happens to my index upon differentiation and why? This is a small step in a larger proof I'm working on...

Given the series representation of Bessel J

$$J_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(k+n)!}(\frac{z}{2})^{2k+n}$$

is the following correct?

$$J'_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (2k+n)}{k!(k+n)!}(\frac{z}{2})^{2k+n-1}$$

I've seen results where the index of the summation has been reindexed... and others where it hasn't. Hence, I'm confused.

I understand that for a power series, the index will be shifted if the first term is a constant and thus is "differentiated away." In this case, though, it's not as clearcut. If $n=0$, then it's a constant, but otherwise it's not. This is my first encounter with Bessel's function by the way.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dJ_n(z)}{dz}=J'_n(z)=J_{n-1}(z)-\frac{n J_n(z)}{z}.$ When you calculate $J'_5(1.1)$ with this expression it gives $0.0017755$, but the answer with your $J'_n(z)$ expression is $-0.000130878$. Thus it may be incorrect.

If you still need the derivative in infinite series form, write this $J_{n-1}(z)-\frac{n J_n(z)}{z}$ as series form using $J_n(z)$ definition.